# How to have antd cell span more than one row?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm learning that Antd lets me create table cells with Row and Col components in place of standard html table cells using tr and td

But if the Antd equivalent of HTML td colspan="3"  is td span={3}  then what is the Antd equivalent of td rowspan="3" ?

Answer (score 0):

From [the examples in the docs](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-jsx), it looks like you're after the ColumnGroup component.